# Parse specific String Javascript (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I would like to parse the following String:

```
{ 
  date: [ 'Thu, 28 Apr 2016 10:56:13 +0200' ],
  subject: [ 'Subject' ],
  from: [ 'Blob <blob@test.com>' ],
  to: [ '<blab@test.com>' ] 
}
```

In order to access the variable `date`, `subject` etc ...

But I am not sure how to do it since it

1. Is not a valid JSON
2. It is not a structure I know

And I don't want to re-invent the wheel if a solution exist which I am not (yet) aware of.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Data are getting using a node-imap module (*only relevant part*)

```
f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
   console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
   var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
   msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
   var buffer = '';
   stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
   buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
});
stream.once('end', function() {
   var parsedHeader = inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer));
   console.log('Author: '+parsedHeader);
});
```

**SOLVED**

See the comment of @stdob--. Imap.parseHeader() return an object.

Comment: @Tushar: I edited my question.

Comment: That looks like valid JSON to me. Its an object of items that are arrays (or a map of lists) with length 1. To access date, do obj.date[0].

Comment: @a.j. It isn't. You can check it out here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @a.j. JSON keys have to enquoted.

Comment: ah yes my bad. but it does seem like a valid Javascript object. which you can convert to JSON using JSON.stringify

Comment: Looks like that `Imap.parseHeader` already returns an object with keys [ https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap#connection-static-methods ]

Comment: I don't recommend it but you can try `eval`, like this: `var data; eval('data = ' + your_string)`

Comment: @stdob-- You're totally right. 
I read too fast ... Thans for your vigilance :)

Comment: @Mornor Try console.log( Object.keys(parsedHeader) )

Comment: @MarkoDumic `var str = 'process.exit()'; eval('data =' + str)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that [`Imap.parseHeader`](http://github.com/mscdex/node-imap#connection-static-methods) already returns an object with keys

Try `console.log( Object.keys(parsedHeader)` to see all the keys.